# Application autostart

Tags: xorg, lightdm

I need to turn on a separate graphical interface when turning on the raspberry, where my application was loaded. I looked at a lot of manuals on google and even asked chatgpt.
I have raspberry pi 3 B+ and 4 B. I tryed Raspbian 10 and 11.
I am using the following commands

```
sudo apt update && apt upgrade -y

sudo apt install openbox xorg lightdm

mkdir -p ~/.config/openbox /usr/lib/myapp/ /usr/share/myapp/

cp -a /etc/xdg/openbox/ ~/.config/
```

I copy project in /usr/lib/myapp and wallpaper.png in /usr/share/myapp

Next i edit the file ~/.config/openbox/autostart

```
setxkbmap -layout us -variant -option grp:lwin_toggle & 
onboard &
feh --bg-fill /usr/share/myapp/wallpaper.png &
while true; do ( DISPLAY=:0 /usr/lib/myapp/myapp /FullScreen; sleep 1; ) done
```

and file /etc/lightdm/lightgdm.conf

```
[Seat:*]
xserver-command=X -nocursor -s 0 dpms
autologin-user=pi
```

Graphical interface starting and nothing happenned. Myapp starting when i logging and type `startx`.
I thing i foggot change some config, any help is welcome.